# Get timeout and rexmut from a r/w request in tftp protocol in c

Tags: c, timeout, tftp

I'm trying to implement a tftp server.
I've got a stucture :

```c
typedef struct {
    u_int16_t opcode;
    char filename[MAXPATH_STRLEN + 1];
    char mode[MAXMODE_STRLEN + 1];
    char timeout[MAXMODE_STRLEN];
    char rexmut[MAXMODE_STRLEN];

} tftp_rwq_hdr;
```

where I accept a r/w request in tftp protol.
When I'm using standart tftp to put a file, listening a request with this structure, I can get the opcode,filename and mode, but I can't get timeout neither rexmut.

So my question is what is the standart way to get the timeout and rexmut from a request like this.